# How to identify new entries in core databases

Tags: sitecore-api

we have got an existing sitecore 8.1 instance complete database. Now we need to identify what are the entries available in the database. in master db we have identified easily by looking into all the used templates and components for the site. for core db we are not sure what are the paths we need to look for identifying new entries. let us know is there a specific way to identify the new item entries from core db ?

Comment: I heard RAZL tool to compare with vanilla instance and identify the new entries . is there any other approach

Answer (score 1):

If you want to analyze the items in the core database to find custom items that are not part of a vanilla Sitecore installation, I suggest to use a serialization engine to serialize the items of the core databases of a vanilla Sitecore 8.1 instance and of your custom Sitecore instance. Then compare the serialized outputs in the file system to find the differences.

If you have access to Sitecore, you can use the OOTB Sitecore serialization engine to serialize the entire content tree of the core database (the serialized files will be stored under the application data folder in the serialization sub-folder). Then you can use an open source software like Beyond Compare or KDiff to compare the two serialized output folders and find the custom differences. The serialization command can be executed from the Developer tab in the Sitecore Content Editor ribbon (if not visible, it can be made visible right-clicking on the ribbon area and selecting the Developer option) using the Serialize tree command.

The major benefit of using the serialization to compare two databases is that you will get a granular delta analysis at field level.

**Example of item-level analysis**

This is an example of analysis using the serialization approach and the `KDiff3` comparison tool between two instances of Sitecore 9.3. One of them has Sitecore Horizon installed.

The serialization process of the entire Core database using the *Serialize Tree* command took less than 5 minutes for each instance for me.

With `KDiff3`, select the two `core` folders in each Sitecore serialization folder (usually stored in each respective instance Data folder) and compare them. The tool initial comparison analysis tells the number of different files found:

[image]

Then expand the folders in the results view to identify the items that are different:

[image]

**Example of field-level analysis**

Once you have identified the different items between the two instances, you can click on each different item in `KDiff3` to access a detailed comparison analysis a field level:

[image]

Comment: is there any tools similar to RAZL as it becomes an licensed version, i cannot able to use it. Incase of File explorer based comparison like beyond compare/Kdiff the readability is not good and its difficult to manually identify the items as a field level b/w databases.

Comment: @JeyanthPraveenkumar I added a couple of examples in my answer. In the approach that I described (that doesn't require to purchase any license), first you should start identifying the different items (usually not too many in a Core database) and then analyze each different item at field level. I haven't said that it is easy, but I don't think it is difficult either.